# Can still see the red dot indicating review queues need attention when on review ban

Tags: bug, review-queues, top-bar

Getting review banned sucks, but it sucks even more to be getting told that the queues need help when you aren't allowed to help.[image]

Seems to me that that has to be a bug; if you are review banned then you shouldn't be getting the red dot indicator at all.

Comment: I'm not review banned, but I get the red dot even when the 3 queues that are open to me are all empty. I've just kind of learned to ignore the red dot.

Comment: Related: [Review queues notifications](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377098/review-queues-notifications)