# Review queues notifications

Tags: support, review-queues, notifications

I have cleared all review queues today, but I'm still getting notified(red circle). Is this a bug or feature? From my perspective:

1. I should be able to do reviews further, even if I have reached daily limit
2. there should be no more notifications for me today
3. notification could be switched off manually

Otherwise it makes no sense to be notified about something, what I can't do.

***PS*** I am not in ban

[image: img]

Comment: Even if not ban-related, the situation is the same. The notification is displayed on page-load, and at that time it is not yet known you do not have any revie tasks available. That information is fetched when you click on the review button.

Comment: @yivi I'm not banned. The workflow is clear, but still problem is not solved. Could information be fetched on page-load or on notification-load? It is bad UX imho

Comment: Never said you were banned. Read again. I'm saying that the situation is the same. Still a dupe.

Comment: @yivi my bad, I am not a native speaker )

Comment: On https://stackoverflow.com/review you can still view the review queues (only reviewing doesn't work, history & stats works).

Comment: @yivi This isn't _close_ to a duplicate of that. While the behavior is the same for context, one is a feature request asking for banned users to not see it, this is a _support_ request wondering if it's a bug that normal users never seem to see the light go out :)

Answer (score 6):

It was always intended to be a signal in the sky, sort of like the bat signal:

[image: Super hero arriving after seeing a signal in the sky]

Except, for performance reasons, the city of Gotham hasn't *yet* been able to coordinate with their engineering department so each citizen gets their own view of it (thus, enabling it to be turned off when civic duty has been done). So for now, when there's stuff to do, we *all* see it.

I don't quite like the current behavior and *if* it's possible to not show it once someone has spent all they can spend reviewing, I'd like to do that, because it adds to the sense of accomplishment.

But, as others pointed out in comments, it's not *known* in advance if this is the case, it fires only on a cached query showing there are tasks to accomplish.

But rest assured, your part in keeping Gotham safe *will be the stuff of legends, and they'll write songs about you!*

Actually, no, they won't, but we really do appreciate you taking the time to complete as many tasks as you can. You're awesome!

Comment: I suppose having one queue that you get 20 reviews for, but it doubles to allowing 40 over a certain size doesn't help, so you can review 20, the queue gets large, you get another 20, but you do 5 which puts it below that size, you then have no more reviews, until later, when you might be able to do more again :)